# Using ESM Modules with Coffeescript and Node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, es6-modules

Ecmascript Modules are the future for packaging JS code, and both Node.js and Coffeescript support them. But I've had some trouble getting their support for ESM to work together.

The current stable Node (12.x) has ESM modules behind a flag (`--experimental-modules`). Coffeescript supports passing flags through to Node with `--nodejs`. So with a couple of files using ESM modules:

```
# a.coffee
import b from './b.coffee'

b()
```

```
# b.coffee
b = ->
  console.log "Hello"

export default b
```

In theory, we can run this code with `npx coffee --nodejs --experimental-modules a.coffee`. In practice this raises an error:

```
13:24 $ npx coffee --nodejs --experimental-modules a.coffee
(node:8923) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
(node:8923) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
/media/projects/coffeemodules/a.coffee:1
import b from './b.coffee';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
...
```

The error and docs say there are two ways to flag a file as containing an ESM module, one is to use the `mjs` extension (which isn't available to us here), and the other is to set `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, which also doesn't seem to work.

So: can it be done? Is there a way to get Coffeescript and Node.js ES modules to play together?